# Covariant and partial derivative of a vector field (not component)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, tensors

Is the covariant derivative of a vector field (not the **components** of a vector) same as the partial derivative?
I am adding a screenshot from page 69 from General Relativity: An introduction for physicists by Hobson where they used the partial derivative operator $\partial_bv$ for **vector field** derivatives, where in other books the covariant derivative operator $\nabla_bv$ is used.

Relevant: is a vector operating on another like $u(v)$ (as in Lie Bracket) also mean covariant derivative of v in the direction of u?
[image: Hobson partial derivative]

Comment: No, the partial derivative is just $\frac{\partial v^a}{\partial x^k}$, this is *not* a tensor. The covariant derivative $\nabla_k v^a$ is a tensor. To add to the confusion sometimes $\nabla_u v$ is the covariant derivative of $v$ in the direction of $u$ and in this case $u$ is not an index, but a vector, using index notation $(\frac{\partial v^a }{\partial x^k }+\Gamma_{k,j}^{a}v^j)u^k$

Answer (score 0):

Your book uses an old point view in differential geometry, where "the covariant derivative of a vector field" $\nabla_i v^j$ is just a coordinate expression which equals the components of "the partial derivative of a vector field", so that
$$\partial_iv = \sum_j(\nabla_iv^j)e_j.$$
This is also the point of view taken in Sokolnikoff's tensor calculus and in Grifeld Tensor calculus and the calculus of moving surfaces, but it is kind of outdated.

In the modern point of view, the "partial derivative of a vector field" (i.e. $\partial_i v$) is not defined, but the same object is called the covariant derivative of $v$ and is denoted $\nabla_i v$, so that its component decomposition is
$$\nabla_iv = \sum_j(\nabla_iv^j)e_j.$$

Comment: Should the modern definition of u(v) be $\nabla_u(v)$, so the Lie Bracket is $[u, v] =  \nabla_u(v) - \nabla_v(u)$ ?

Comment: @Nayeem1 I'm not aware of a (former or modern) definition of $u(v)$. I only know about the Lie bracket $L_uv=[u,v]=\nabla_uv-\nabla_vu$ (where $\nabla$ is a torsion-less connection). Where have you seen $u(v)$?

Comment: Here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields

Comment: @Nayeem1 I can't find what you mean. It makes sense to apply a vector field to a function. If $v$ is a vector field and $f$ is a function, then $v(f)$ is another function, so it makes sense to apply $u$ to it and obtain $u(v(f))$. But nowhere in that article can I find such a thing as $u(v)$.

Comment: So $u(v(f))= \nabla_u (v(f))$?

Comment: Yes, that is right, @Nayeem1. In general, $\nabla_u(f)=u(f)$.

Comment: Well, that gives rise to another problem. Torsion will be Lie - Lie, hence always zero. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_tensor

Comment: @Nayeem1 No, torsion is $T(u,v)=\nabla_uv-\nabla_vu-[u,v]=\nabla_uv-\nabla_vu-L_uv$. That's why, when torsion vanishes (i.e. $T=0$) you have $[u,v]=L_uv=\nabla_uv-\nabla_vu$. Anyway, that is a separate question so you can ask a open a new post for that if you can't find an answer already in the site. If you think my answer solves your current question (i.e. this post), you can close the post clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it replied the 1st part of my question. I should probably open a second thread for the second part.